# ¿ Como recuperar JSON de servicio Java?

Tags: json, rest, java-ee, gson

Estoy creando un servicio REST expuesto desde Java, estoy trabajando en Netbeans porque vi que era muchisimo mas fácil la generación del código a partir del modelo de base de datos que tengo ya definido y creado, ahora bien el servicio me funciona pero me devuelve todos los datos como XML, utilice la libreria GSON de Google y me funciona con datos individuales pero no con listas tipo List, cuando estaba trabajando con Eclipse, con solo incluir la libreria Jersey-json en el classpath ya era suficiente para que devolviese el JSON (utilizaba maven), en Netbeans incluso incluyendo las librerias en el pom.xml no me funciona, estoy ingresando estas librerias en el POM:

> javax.ws.rs
>       javax.ws.rs-api
>       2.1
>
> com.sun.jersey
>       jersey-json
>       1.19.4

Pero obtengo el resultado de la imagen cuando llamo a alguna función que solo permita expulsar valores en JSON:

[image: Mensaje de salida del servidor Glassfish]

No quiero tener que parsear en Java o en JavaScript las respuestas, no es la idea, de todas maneras como ya comentaba, en Java con GSON no me esta funcionando del todo bien. En el lado Front estoy utilizando Angular pero no creo que eso ayude mucho porque este tema es de servidor, glassfish y javaee.

Comment: Puedes visitar: [Java JSON Example](https://www.journaldev.com/2315/java-json-example)

Comment: Ricardo, tu pregunta fue reportada como "baja calidad" **por la comunidad, por favor revisar [ask]**.